# Access mdb form set CheckBox if Date is not NULL

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm trying to set this checkBox on list view and can't make it work, is something is wrong with my syntax.
I used this syntax and other variation, but box is still greyout

```
=IIf([tblConfirm]![ReceiptDate] Is Null,"False","True")
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is you're referring to a tbl but not indicating what record you are looking at it. Is this data part of a subform?

Comment: Tx D!  No, this is plain multi line form with dynaset, if I set source for this chkBox directly to table  Yes/No column It works correctly, also I can display that ReceiptDate in Date format on that form too.

Comment: So is tblConfirm a table or a subform? I think i would need more detail before i can help

Comment: tblConfirm is table,  ReceiptDate is Date format field in this table.

Comment: So again the issue is related to what record in that table are you trying to check against? Is this a temp table that gets filled by the form?

Comment: No, it's all straight forward and simple, all tables are objects in mdb.  I just want to display  value of ReceiptDate (Date Format)  in   Boolean chkBox  ( Yes/No),  This is DynaSet list which works perfectly, I just adding new chBox.

Comment: Doesn't appear that you know how to mark your questions as answered. That's an important task in this forum of volunteers. Please indicate you value their responses

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use:

```
=IsNull([tblConfirm].[ReceiptDate])

' or:

=[tblConfirm].[ReceiptDate] Is Null
```

and then apply a format of *True/False*.

Comment: Tx G!!!!  What is <apply a format  True/False>, I played with it in Source and Default filed and doesn't work, still grayed out which I think indicates wrong format.

Comment: This is basically same like on my original post, just without IIF

Comment: I don't think he knows how - not one question has been answered to his satisfaction apparently